# How do I get a variation measure of z-scores with different underlying n's per group?

Tags: statistical-significance, variance

I need to confirm a stats question and I was wondering if you could
let me know whether you would agree with my thought process:

would need this good enough for publication purposes in a Psychology journal, for what reason I am a little unsure:

Essentially: How do I get a variation measure of z-scores with different underlying n's per group?

For example, 3 groups with 8 z-scores (each representing a different test result), n1=10 per z-score,n2=8 per z-score,n3=12 per z-score.
I would go and simply get a variation measure (SD) for each data point (z-score) by forming a new SD from each z-score, with the typical SD formula=Sqrt of Sum (individual z-score-mean of z per group)2/N-1.
And then use this SD average score and create a variation score for each z-score per group,which should give the basis for running a significance test on this variation measure for the three groups.
Would you go about this the same way? Have you perhaps come across anything like that before?

Appreciative of any help.

#### Edit

I attach a table with the z-scores: 3 columns are Group 1, Group 2, Group 3; the first 8 rows are the z-scores for the 3 Groups on the 8 different tests.

```
Group1    Group2    Group3
  1.93      0.45      1.21  
  1.32      1         0.95  
  0.88      1.42      1.22  
  0.86      1.51      0.9   
  0.76      0.62      0.94  
  0.62      0.81      0.96  
  0.38      0.6       0.86  
  0.9       1.33      1.31  
   ?         ?         ?           SD
  0.95625   0.9675    1.04375       M
  0.4650928 0.3974056 0.1554443    Coefficient of variation (V)
  47         40       15           V as %
```

Row 9 is the SD

Row 10 is the mean

Row 11 is the Coefficient of Variation and this is converted to % in Row 12.

I hope that makes it all a bit clearer.

Comment: z-scores are variation measures. I think you're trying to describe an ANOVA: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_variance but I'm not sure. Can you say what your research question is, and what sort of data you have?

Comment: As far as I understand it z-scores are standardized scores, where we set the mean to 0 and sd to 1. If I now take the mean and SD of the 3 groups, each with 8 z-scores from different tests (with different underlying n) I am violating homogeneity of variance assumption for ANOVA. Then just running a non-parametric alternative seems also not right as the underlying n per z-score is different. These are different neuropsychological tests, which are standardized to compare across tests.

Comment: Each z-score is the distance between the raw score and the population mean in units of the standard deviation. You now seem to want to take standard deviations of the z-scores. I do not understand why you wish to do that. What data do you have and what do you want to know?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help Michelle. And I am sorry to make this more complicated than it probably needs to be. In a nutshell, I want to show the SD (or Coefficient of Variance) between the z-scores of 8 tests for 3 groups is significantly different. The means are the same but the SD of 1 group is low while the SD of the other 2 groups is much larger.

The usual ANOVA with Homogeneity of Variances is not showing this – likely due to only 8 data points for each group (these are z-scores of the mean of 3 groups of n = 10, n = 8, n = 12 when compared to controls of n = 35).

Comment: :) I think I am starting to understand your situation better. You say you have 8 tests, and you say that the SD of group 1 is low. Are you combining the results of the 8 tests into one composite measure, or are you doing 8 separate comparisons - 1 per test? And when you say "test result", is that like a total score across a number of stimuli/questions, or is each test just one question/stimulus? An example of the type of data you have would be really useful.

Comment: Why is there no negative z-scores? I think you are better off working in terms of the raw data.  You are confusing yourself, and i don't think what you are doing is standard.